# is "which" a function in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, system

I'm trying to use 'which python3' in MATLAB's system command, and it doesn't work. The goal here is to write a script that can run a specific version of python without hard-coding the path into the script. I'd like the script to find python3 and then call it by the full pathname.

When I run the following command in MATLAB,

```
>> [stat, result] = system('which python3')
```

I get the following output:

```
stat =

 1

result =

 0x0 empty char array
```

However, I can run the following command in UNIX and get a good result:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Additionally, this works fine in MATLAB:

```
>> [stat, result] = system('which python')
stat =

 0

result =

'/usr/bin/python
'
```

and in UNIX

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: It works on my system. What version of matlab are you using?

Comment: Since you're specifying "in Unix", is the first call on Windows?  If that's the case, `where` is the closest analogue to `which`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've been working on MATLAB 2017b (student version) on Mac OS Sierra in all cases. To clarify, when I say, "in UNIX", I mean in the Mac OS terminal. It's the exact same computer on which I run the which command (from within MATLAB and the Mac OS terminal).

Answer (score 1):

I got [some help on this one from the "MATLAB Answers" forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/359408-trouble-with-a-command-in-matlab-s-system?s_tid=email_ans_new_ans_ans_h). User Walter Robertson told me

> MATLAB typically is launched as a graphics program by the operating systems. Such programs do not execute the user's login scripts, so environment variables are not set to user login values: they stay at the system defaults.
>
> system() does not run scripts in a "login" context, so profile variables are not set up either.
>
> The only thing that executes are the scripts that are run every time a
> shell is initialized.

Thus, my login script wasn't run, so the path to Python 3 wasn't included in the context from which MATLAB's system runs the which command, so I get an empty result from system.